# How to transfer localhost mysql database to remote host mysql database when a BTN clicked in java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a java swing application, connecting with localhost mysql database and it works charm. However i want an option by which my localhost database anytime fully backup in remote hosting mysql database which will mirror of my current localhost database.

I already created a database as same name of my localhost db. I am searching lot, but can't find any solution in this issue.

**localhost db (inventory) --> BTN ClICK --> Fully Mirror Copy--> remotehost db (inventory)**

Comment: Do you want to be able access the remote database through JDBC (or any other means) - because you could just backup the database file to remote server instead

Comment: I can access my remote database by JDBC. But problem is, my database is running in localhost. I want localhost database fully copy in remote database. By using cpanel i can do it manually. 

localhost mysql database --> export from phpmyadmin -> login cpanel 
->browse remote phpmyadmin database -> import database to it.

I want whole process in a simple JBUTTON click from software.